# remove y scaled label in pgfplot graph

Tags: pgfplots

I wanted to divide the y coordinate values by 1050 so i used scaled y ticks=real:1050

Here is my code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled y ticks=real:1050,
height=9cm,
width=15cm,
grid=major,
xlabel={Levels},
ylabel={Accu},
legend style={
cells={anchor=east},
legend pos=outer north east,
}
]
```

I need to remove the .1,050 label from the graph. Does anyone know how to remove it ?

[image]
after doing ytick scale label code/.code={}, that label went away, but now iam left with a new problem on a another graph of mine. The y axis goes beyond the 1 value. I only need the graph to show upto y value of 1. As shown here the graph goes upto 1.07

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ytick scale label code/.code={}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled y ticks=real:1050,
ytick scale label code/.code={},
height=9cm,
width=15cm,
grid=major,
xlabel={Levels},
ylabel={Accu},
legend style={
cells={anchor=east},
legend pos=outer north east,
}
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding the option `ymax=<value>`, for the appropriate `<value>`, will solve the problem mentioned in the edit to the original question.

Comment: Iam now left with a new problem. I updated my question. My graph displays beyond y = 1

Comment: @user581544 adding the option `ymax=1` should do the job.

Comment: actually ymax=1050 worked

Comment: @user581544 Ah, of course, I forgot the multiplicative factor.